# Why there are few transaction before the Contract Creation txn?

Tags: tokens, wallets, evm, addresses, smart-contract-wallets

Does anyone know in this smart contract (see screenshot below) why there are few transaction before the smart contract creation txn?

It seem like this smart contract was previously a normal EVM wallet address, but now it became smart contract, i thought each address was fix on blockchain, which means wallet remain wallet, and smart contract remain smart contract, or are they able to convert into each other in some special situation?

[image]

Comment: Could you send the etherscan URL of the address?

Comment: EOAs do not turn into contract addresses. If you share the specific contract we can look exactly at what it is. Incoming txn's to contact or outgoing from deployer etc.
But you are not showing enough there.

Answer (score 0):

As asked in the comments, it'd really help clarify your issue if you could please provide the address plus network information of the contract in question.

However, I can tell you that there are only two type of accounts in use by the EVM. The first one is the EOA (externally owned account), i.e. wallet (as you put it), and then there's the smart contract account. I can with a high degree of certainty tell you, that those two types of accounts never can be converted into each other, since the EOA makes use of a private key, which the smart contract account doesn't.

So, what I believe you're looking at right here is a smart contract account that deploys a new contract. You can see the methods called are methods called on a smart contract. The transaction fee is also ~9 times higher than for the other methods called on this contract, which makes me think, that we're talking about a new deployment from the smart contract in question.

I hope this will help with some clarification! :)

Answer (score 0):

the "Contract Creation" you show refers to a new contract created by the contract you are viewing.